# How to receive a copied image in MobileSafari?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, web-applications, clipboard

I'm building an iOS website, and I'm trying to get the recently copied image using JavaScript.

When you hold your finger on a photo in a website a menu will pop-out with the option to **Save the image** or **Copy**. When you press copy and paste it later in a text-field, you can get the URL with:

```
pasteEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/uri-list');
```

When you copy an image in the camera roll, facebook application, or by selecting and you go to the same text-field (or textarea) the paste option is not available, however when going to the Mail.application the Paste option is available and pasts the image. So does anyone have a clue how to get the URL or binary data for a copied photo on an iPad?

Apple Documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/CopyAndPaste.html

Example:

http://codebits.glennjones.net/editing/getclipboarddata.htm

Comment: +1 and edited your question to reflect it's not about native development.

Comment: iPad web application : distributed through the appStore (packaged with a framework such as Phonegap) or is it accessible through a web browser ?

Answer (score 1):

This won't be possible for a website to do, as the javascript won't have direct access to any native elements.

*if* however, you are hosting a webview in a native application, a-la phonegap ... then you may be able to do something here by handling the paste in native code, and then making it available to the webview.